# What percentage of farm animals are mistreated in some way?

Tags: outreach, livestock-industry, animal-welfare, statistics

Many non-veg*ns agree that various practices on farms are cruel and do not wish to support them, but believe that the practices are rare. Is this true? I'm looking for statistics from any country on the frequency of farm animal abuse. Sources are required, preferably recent, credible, and unbiased.

Comment: "I want to collect as much data as possible to counter this belief" You are basically asking only for data which support your claim, which is ethically extremely dubious at best.

Comment: @Fatalize I'm perfectly happy to leave out data if there's evidence that it's wrong (see the first bullet point for example). Other data along the lines of "only 1% of farms do X" doesn't prove or disprove anything on either side and is of no interest to anyone - it can't change the fact that 80% of farms still do Y and Z. So I don't think there's anything intellectually dishonest. I'm not presenting anything false, I'm not leaving out anything pertinent, so in no way am I being misleading.

Comment: @Fatalize I see I'm getting downvoted now, is there something in my comment that wasn't convincing?

Comment: I have not downvoted your question so I cannot say why it was. Your comment does not change the fact that you ask this question in a biased way. Although you indicate that credible, unbiased sources are required, one gets the impression through the first part of the question that this is not what you're looking for (e.g. "being an ethical omnivore is not easy", which is uncalled for). Getting rid of it would change the question for the better I think.

Comment: @Fatalize thanks, you're right that I was a bit careless in my wording. I've actually gotten rid of most of the question, there's no longer any need for so much detail. The answer should speak for itself.

Comment: To the close voters: This question isn't too broad, as it asks specifically for answers backed up by studies. It's not asking for people to list all the studies, one or two + a summary of them will work.

Comment: Actual farms, as in ranches and classically run farms, or CAFO operations (in which case I dare polemically say "100 percent.". Yes, that is opinionated.)?

Comment: @rackandboneman both, or either. See the second comment on the answer. If you have a stat to add, let me know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Chickens

### Egg-laying hens

> An estimated **95% of all eggs** in the United States are produced in conventional cage systems, sometimes called **battery cages**. [They] typically provide each laying hen an average of 67 square inches of floor space. In some egg operations, hens have less space.

[**Source:** Table Egg Production and Hen Welfare:
Agreement and Legislative Proposals - 2014](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R42534.pdf)

Statistics for many other countries can be found in: [Statistics: Laying Hens - Compassion in World Farming - 2013](https://www.ciwf.org.uk/media/5235021/Statistics-Laying-hens.pdf). There's too much data to paste here. The percentages range all the way from 0 to 100.

From the same report:

> Between 87% and 100% of laying hens producing eggs for all except one of the supermarkets surveyed are beak-trimmed. Only Waitrose reported a much lower proportion (36%) of hens being beak-trimmed. Overall, **probably at least 90% of laying hens in the UK are beak-trimmed**

---

> Induced molting usually involves **removal of feed for periods of 5 to 14 days**  followed by a low nutrient ration for the remaining days in a 28 day molt program. [...] Molting programs involve an estimated **75-80% of the commercial flocks** in the US.

[**Source:** Proceedings of the 50th Western Poultry Disease Conference - 2001](http://www.acpv.info/assets/WPDC/wpdcproceedings_2001.pdf)

---

### Broiler (meat) chickens

> Studies consistently show that approximately **26-30% of broiler chickens** suffer from gait defects severe enough to **impair walking ability**, and additional research strongly suggests that birds at this level of lameness are **in pain**.

[**Source:** An HSUS Report: The Welfare of Animals in
the Meat, Egg, and Dairy Industries](http://www.humanesociety.org/assets/pdfs/farm/welfare_overview.pdf). 5 references are cited for this sentence. From [one of those references](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0001545):

> We assessed the walking ability of 51,000 birds, representing 4.8 million birds within 176 flocks. [...] over 27.6% of birds in our study showed poor locomotion and 3.3% were almost unable to walk. [This is] despite culling policies designed to remove severely lame birds from flocks.

Therefore it's safe to regard these numbers as typical.

---

> In 2011, 15,951 commercial operations raised broilers for meat in the 17 sample States

A table then shows that these farms produced 8,060,557,235 broilers in 2011, an average of over **500,000 chickens per operation**.

[**Source:** Technology, Organization, and Financial Performance in U.S. Broiler Production (USDA) - 2014](https://www.ers.usda.gov/webdocs/publications/eib126/48159_eib126.pdf)

---

## Cows

From the [Executive Summary of the 2007
National Market Cow and Bull
Beef Quality Audit](http://www.bqa.org/Media/BQA/Docs/2007auditbeef.pdf) about cows (whether raised for beef or dairy) being brought to slaughter:

> **83%** of all plants used **electric prods** for moving cattle to the restrainer. 65% used electric cattle prods on more than 25% of their cattle. [...] 39% of plants audited showed the aggressive use of [other] driving aids when moving cattle to the restrainer.

**49% of dairy cows** showed some level of **lameness** in holding pens (see graph on page 7).

---

> Steers weighing 500 pounds and over totaled 16.4 million head, up slightly from one year ago. Bulls weighing 500 pounds and over totaled 2.23 million head

Since steers are castrated and bulls are not, **88% of male cows** are castrated.

[**Source:** USDA cattle inventory - 2017](http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/usda/current/Catt/Catt-01-31-2017.pdf)

Furthermore, **pain relief isn't used 70 - 80%** of the time:

> Respondents reported not providing analgesic drugs to approximately 70% of calves castrated at < 6 months of age.

[**Source:** Analgesic drug administration and attitudes about analgesia in cattle among bovine practitioners in the United States - 2011](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21401433)

> One in five practitioners report using an analgesic or local anesthetic at the time of castration.

[**Source:** A survey of castration methods and associated livestock management practices performed by bovine veterinarians in the United States - 2009](http://bmcvetres.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1746-6148-6-12)

---

### Dairy cows

> approximately **88% of Norwegian dairy cattle, 75% of all Swedish dairy herds and more than one third of German dairy cows are kept in tie-stall housing systems**, often without pasturing. According to the 2007 USDA report **62% of US dairy farms** had tie-stall barns. In Romania, the tied system is used in approximately **75% of the middle sized and large farms and in 90% of the small farms**

[**Source:** Dairy cows welfare quality in tie-stall housing system with or without access to exercise](https://actavetscand.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1751-0147-55-43)

(this means that the cow is ["held by a neck chain, strap, or stanchion such that she can lie down but cannot turn around"](http://www.humanesociety.org/assets/pdfs/farm/welfare_overview.pdf))

---

From [Heifer Calf Health and Management Practices on U.S. Dairy Operations, 2007](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/animal_health/nahms/dairy/downloads/dairy07/Dairy07_ir_CalfHealth.pdf):

> Overall, **94.0 percent of operations routinely dehorned heifer calves** while they were on the operation during the previous 12 months. A lower percentage of large operations (64.3 percent) dehorned heifer calves than small or medium operations (97.3 and 92.6 percent, respectively). [...] For operations that routinely dehorned heifer calves during the previous 12 months, more than two-thirds **(69.1 percent) used a hot iron** [...] For operations that used a hot iron to dehorn calves, **13.8 percent used analgesics/anesthetics** when dehorning calves.

> Tail docking is currently prohibited in California and must not be
>   performed as a routine management procedure in the European Union. [...] About half of operations [in the U.S.] (51.4 percent) had no cows with the tail docked. [...] On about one of seven operations (14.6 percent), all cows had the tail docked. [...] Overall, about 4 of 10 cows **(38.8 percent) had the tail docked**. [...] The majority of operations with tail-docked cows **(90.3 percent) did not routinely use analgesics or anesthetics** for tail docking, compared with 1.1 percent that routinely used analgesics or anesthetics. Operations that routinely used analgesics or anesthetics represented 0.9 percent of cows with the tail
>   docked.

> About one-half of operations **(50.3 percent) routinely removed extra teats** from heifer calves [...] One of 10 operations **(10.6 percent) routinely used analgesia or anesthesia** during extra teat removal

---

**94.9% of operations** observed at least one case of clinical **mastitis**, a painful, inflammatory infection of the udder caused by milking. **16.5% of cows** had mastitis in 2006, as identified by producers.

[**Source**: Dairy 2007, Part I: Reference of Dairy Cattle Health and Management Practices in the United States](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/animal_health/nahms/dairy/downloads/dairy07/Dairy07_dr_PartI.pdf)

Surveys on mastitis in Nordic countries in 1997 found:

> 18.3 cases per 100 completed or terminated lactations in Sweden to 25.8 per 100 cow-years in Norway

[**Source**: Cumulative Risk of Bovine Mastitis Treatments in Denmark, Finland, Norway and Sweden](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1820994/)

---

## Pigs

> By far the most common system in use is the **farrowing crate**, with an estimated **85% of all sows** in the U.S. being housed in this type of system at farrowing.

[**Source:** Swine Welfare Fact Sheet (USDA) - 2011](https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/50201500/Farrowing%20System%20Fact%20Sheet.pdf)

([a farrowing crate is a metal enclosure only slightly bigger than the sow that she spends 4-5 weeks in around the time of giving birth](http://www.viva.org.uk/resources/campaign-materials/fact-sheets/farrowing-crate))

---

> One in every four sows (26 per cent) is bred outdoors in the UK, but just one in twenty pigs (5 per cent) spend the growing period outdoors and **one in a hundred are finished on free range**.

> **56 per cent** of UK sows farrow in some form of **farrowing crate**

[**Source**: Structure of the UK Pig Industry](http://www.thepigsite.com/articles/2512/structure-of-the-uk-pig-industry/)

---

> only 17.3 percent of sows spend a portion of gestation in open pens. Plain surveyed pork operations with 1,000 or more sows. He received responses from 70 operations, which combined own about 3.6 million of the nation’s 5.7 million sows.

[**Source**: Survey Shows Few Sows In Open Housing - National Hog Farmer - 2012](http://www.nationalhogfarmer.com/animal-well-being/survey-shows-few-sows-open-housing)

This means that the other **82.7% of sows from these operations spend almost their entire pregnancies (114 days) in small gestation crates**.

---

**77% of pigs are castrated without pain relief** in 26 European countries:

> approximately 20% are left entire, less than 3% are castrated with anaesthesia and the rest are castrated without anaesthesia

[**Source:** Practice on castration of piglets in Europe - 2009](https://ec.europa.eu/food/sites/food/files/animals/docs/aw_prac_farm_pigs_cast-alt_detection_2009_eur-piglet-practice.pdf)

> In the USA **virtually all males are physically castrated** at a young age (predominantly) with **no anesthesia** or analgesia (pain relief).

[**Source:** Pig Castration - Texas Tech University](http://www.depts.ttu.edu/animalwelfare/Research/PigCastration/)

---

Pigs in barren, crowded environments cannot perform natural behaviours and get frustrated, which commonly leads to biting tails on other pigs. Farmers often deal with this by docking (cutting) piglets' tails. EU law requires that pigs are given environment enrichment such as straw for stimulation and are housed well (e.g. not too densely) to avoid tail biting. Tail docking must be a last resort. An investigation found that **44 out of 45** pig farms in 6 countries in the EU **failed to meet these legal requirements**, by not providing effective environment enrichment and routinely tail docking piglets.

[**Source**: Widespread Breaches of Pig Welfare Laws in the EU Summary Report - 2013](http://spolecnostprozvirata.cz/wp-content/uploads/Summary-report_pig_20131.pdf)

---

> For the 2014 production year, **93 percent** of the annual pig crop was produced on operations with **at least 5,000 head**

[**Source**: 2015 Overview of the United States Hog Industry - USDA](http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/usda/current/hogview/hogview-10-29-2015.pdf)

Comment: It seems the simplest math would be to subtract the percentage of family farms from the percentage of agribusiness facilities and you have your answer. 100% of U.S. factory farms abuse 100% of their animals.

Comment: @M.Mat no. I explained why that doesn't work in the question but I'll expand. Supposedly [96% of US farms (including crop farms) are family owned](https://fsa.blogs.govdelivery.com/2013/08/07/report-96-percent-of-farms-are-family-owned/) which gives the opposite impression of the stats in this answer. And [this article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/phillempert/2015/06/15/why-factory-farming-isnt-what-you-think/#423375376065) claims that factory farms are not necessarily that big and can "be considerate towards the animals’ life-quality." I'm circumventing this kind of problem.

Comment: I'll reread your question; I was somewhat flip in my comment. I deeply believe eating animals is morally wrong and their mistreatment affects me greatly.

Comment: Excellent answer! Be careful on the interpretation of the 96% stat. That's only in relation to crops, not animal farms ([see page 47 of the report](https://www.ers.usda.gov/webdocs/publications/err152/39359_err152.pdf?v=41526)). Since there are far fewer animal farms, large companies have been able to monopolise more easily, and where there aren't monopolies, there are large coops. Also, I'd be very careful about the "small farm = less suffering (per animal)" assumption. In my experience that's not true so I'd like to see stats.

Comment: A large number of these references are US-specific.

Comment: @Pharap yup, that's just what I found the most data about. I'd love to include more data from other countries.

Comment: @AlexHall It is indeed difficult to find actual figures in amongst news articles, but [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/uk-unites-to-stamp-out-battery-cages)'s an article from the UK Government itself outlining some past figures and alterations regarding battery farming that might still be relevant. More examples can be found [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/policies/animal-welfare).

Comment: @Pharap the first link talks about how battery cages should be stamped out by 2012 so it's not really a helpful source. The second link is a huge dump of information that I don't want to sift through. Honestly it was exhausting putting together what I have so far, I would really appreciate some contributions from others.

Comment: @AlexHall The numbers are in the 'Notes' section at the bottom. e.g "In 2010, the UK was home to 33 million laying hens. UK table egg industry worth £561m (2010). UK production 826 million dozen table eggs annually from the following farming methods: 50% cages (conventional or enriched); 42% free range; 8.3% (barn & organic) (2010); Industry estimate the UK market split for 2012 to be 43% enriched cage, 50% free range (of which 3% would be organic) and 4% barn;" Granted there's a lot of info in the second link, I don't have time to look through it all now either, sadly.

Comment: @Pharap I saw that, but like I said, the article suggests quite strongly that those numbers are likely to have changed by now. They're supposedly scanning eggs with UV light to find battery cages. I think a more recent source is required to show whether the ban has been effective.